# Running .net Core App in Dockers generates File Not Found Error

Tags: docker, .net-core

I am running a .net core application on Dockers. At first it kept on slamming me with "FileNotFound_FileName": "/usr/share/dotnet/appsettings.json" error. I fixed it with replacing

```
//string baseDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
string baseDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

and now the app runs okay in Dockers but only in debug mode. When i switch to release i still see the same notorious file not found message. **"FileNotFound_FileName": "/usr/share/dotnet/appsettings.json"**. It has resorted back to the original location. Any help understand what is going on here?

I have cleaned nuget cache, cleaned the project, rebuilt it. Even closed VS2019 and launched it again. But app still gives the same error in release mode.

Comment: By default, the appsettings.json file is not mandatory. Can you show any relevent code related to appsettings.json? And also give the full stack trace. There is not enough detail here to work with.

Comment: I believe Dockers expects file to be at /usr/share/dotnet/appsettings.json by default. So when i can changed the baseDirectory to point to the app binaries it got fixed at least in Debug mode. In release it is still the same story.

Comment: sorry, I just rewrote my comment after I reread your question. Please can you kindly answer my updated comment instead! Thanks :) please edit your question with any new details :)

Comment: There are a few configuration settings in the file therefore i am reading it specifically. The stack trace goes something like

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in Unity.Container.dll: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
Stack trace:
 >   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
 >   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)

Comment: Please edit your question to give us _the code you are using to register appsettings_ and _the full stack trace_ and _any other relevant code_ (e.g. the code where you set up the unity container and the configuration). We cannot help you unless you show us what you have done.